# How can I add a stylesheet to the Classic Editor page?

Tags: css, visual-editor, post-editor, admin-css

I want to make some style changes to the Classic Editor page itself -- not the place where you write the text of the post, but the main part of the page (such as the Categories block -- maybe I want to reposition it on the page, or change its color, or something).  This isn't a job for `add-editor-style()`, and the editor page isn't part of my theme, so it doesn't go there.  Any tips on where I can do this?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not particularly clear on what you're attempting to accomplish. You mean to modify the layout of the Classic Editor plugin's interface? (aside but notable, the WordPress Foundation is ceasing support for that plugin at the end of this year). This is the intended application for `add_editor_style()`, and there's nothing wrong with a theme adding an editor style - this is done frequently to match front-end and dashboard styling. If you do not wish to do so in a theme, then in a plugin :)

Comment: Depending on your modifications, it would be better to use more appropriate hooks than just hiding elements with CSS

Comment: Agreed on hooks > style, but I'm enough of a wp newbie that I couldn't find the right hooks.  Also, I tried the add_editor_style() thing, but that seemed to load the stylesheet into the iframe containing the editing region, not the page itself.  Thanks for the notes; I guess I should go back and look/hack some more.